# raw_input() not working correctly?

Tags: python, raw-input

Ok,

So I'm working on a simple text rpg (in Python) currently.  But for some reason, one of my functions is reading inputs weird.

Right now, each room in the dungeon is a separate function.  Here is the room that isn't working:

```
def strange_room():

    global fsm
    global sword
    global saw

    if not fsm:
        if not saw:
            print "???..."
            print "You're in an empty room with doors on all sides."
            print "Theres a leak in the center of the ceiling... strange."
            print "In the corner of the room, there is an old circular saw blade leaning against the wall."
            print "What do you want to do?"

            next6 = raw_input("> ")

            print "next6 = ", next6

            if "left" in next6:
                zeus_room()

            elif "right" in next6:
                hydra_room()

            elif "front" or "forward" in next6:
                crypt_room()

            elif ("back" or "backwad" or "behind") in next6:
                start()

            elif "saw" in next6:
                print "gothere"
                saw = True
                print "Got saw."
                print "saw = ", saw
                strange_room()

            else:
                print "What was that?"
                strange_room()

        if saw:
            print "???..."
            print "You're in an empty room with doors on all sides."
            print "Theres a leak in the center of the ceiling... strange."
            print "What do you want to do?"

            next7 = raw_input("> ")

            if "left" in next7:
                zeus_room()

            elif "right" in next7:
                hydra_room()

            elif "front" or "forward" in next7:
                crypt_room()

            elif ("back" or "backwad" or "behind") in next7:
                start()

            else:
                print "What was that?"
                strange_room()
```

My issue is with getting my input.  This function executes up until line 17.  It seems to take an input the first time around, but the print statement to print the input doesn't execute.  Then, on top of that, only the left, right, and front/forward commands work correctly.  Anything else I type in only executes the crypt_room() function that "front"/"forward" should execute.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this coded in python?

Comment: @Bry6n Yes.  I completely forgot to mention that.  Will edit it in.

Comment: I'm having troubles booting this up to see the problem, due to none of the globals being defined at the beginning, and thus a failure in the if's... but I'll keep working.

Comment: Judjing by the design of your room, I'd say that your program have problems far exceeding your raw_input error, a good idea might be to ask for advice on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) (maybe start by posting the begininnig).

Comment: @Bry6n The whole thing is somewhere in the range of 500 lines long, so I didn't want to post the whole thing. But I can if you're that inclined to help.

Comment: @RikPoggi I will take a look at that site as well. Thanks.

Comment: @RikPoggi: codereview isn't for code that doesn't work.

Comment: @Wooble: I wasn't suggesting to post there the code presented here, or to migrate there this question, but that might be useful for the OP to open a question with the first 50-100 lines of his program asking for a review.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression

```
"front" or "forward" in next6
```

evaluates to `"front"` and is always considered true in an `if` statement.  What you probably mean is

```
"front" in next6 or "forward" in next6
```

There are more mistakes of this type in your code.  In general, the expression

```
A or B
```

evaluates to `A` if `A` is [truthy](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) and to `B` otherwise.

As a side note, the whole design of your program is broken.  The recursive calls when entering different rooms will quickly hit the maximum recursion depth.

Comment: +1 Good point about all these programming mistakes, inconsistencies etc. There is also a lot that can be improved in terms of readability & code simplicity.

Comment: Also, I will have to read up more on recursion then.  I will look for a better way to implement the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

Sven Marnach said why your code doesn't work. To make it work right, you should use `any()`::

```
("back" or "backwad" or "behind") in next6:
```

should be

```
any(direction in next6 for direction in ("back", "backwad", "behind")):
```